# How to increase the speed of sliding sidebar?

Tags: javascript

I have created a sliding sidebar for my website, using Jquery. I took help from http://www.formget.com/how-to-design-sidebar-sliding-contact-form-with-javascript/# to develop this feature.

I want to increase the speed of sliding form, how to do that?

Please help me...

Comment: 1. Why is that tagged with jQuery? The provided code is not jQuery. 2. What an ugly way to slide a DIV...

Comment: I can help you but only after you respond to my comment

Comment: You have to provide relevant code you are using in question. Just linking to a third party plugin and asking for help isn't the purpose of this website

Comment: Because I want to speed up the slider, and I think that can be with the help of jquery that's why I tagged with jqery

Answer (score 0):

The javascript removes 2 pixels at a time in the following line:

```
slidingDiv.style.right = parseInt(slidingDiv.style.right) - 2 + "px";
```

If you increase the 2 to 4 it should move twice as fast. You can make this number any value you want to speed up or slow down.